# How to break infinite while in Arduino

Tags: while-loop, arduino, break, infinite

A-R-D-U-I-N-O circuit that include pad number and a led with this code

```
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'*','0','#','D'}
};

void setup() {
    pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    char key = keypad.getKey();

    if (key) {
        Serial.println(key);
        switch(key) {
            case 'A': 
            while(1)
            {
                digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
                delay(1000);
                digitalWrite(13,LOW);
                delay(1000);
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

How can I make another case e.g. (case 'D') to stop this infinite while loop?

Comment: what language is this

Comment: You won't be able to make such a thing. Using an infinite loop in this way shouldn't be a good idea. Try another way to control, for example, measureing time with `millis()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't exit the while loop therefore you will keep running the code

```
digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
delay(1000);
digitalWrite(13,LOW);
delay(1000);
```

You will never leave this loop in order to be able to run a case such as Case 'D'. You will need to put an if statement within the while loop that checks for whatever you want to be true. If it is true then you should `break;`

```
if (statement) break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually you can't break that while from outside since the program will only be running those instructions inside the while loop. Maybe you should use another strategie. One would be the use of another variable that saves the option.
Something like:

```
void loop(){

int option = 0;

char key = keypad.getKey();

if (key)
{
   Serial.println(key);
   switch(key){
     case 'A': option = 1; break;
     case 'B': option = 2; break;
   }
}

if(option == 1)
{
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);
  delay(1000);
}
else if(option == 2)
{...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your "switch" case is a little malformed, I thought they always had to have a default case. Your code also seems to be missing the keypad includes/defines.

As for the problem could always have a flag that the two buttons turned on/off and then blink the led depending on that flag.

```
#include <Keypad.h>
const byte ROWS = 4;
const byte COLS = 4;

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {5, 6, 7, 8}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {A3, A2, A1, A0}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad

Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(Keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);
//yes i know that looks horrible 
//would always have a different name for the keypad myself

char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'*','0','#','D'}
};
int flag=0;

void setup() {
pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  char key = keypad.getKey();

  if (key) {
    Serial.println(key);
    switch(key) {
        case 'A': 
          flag=1;
          break;

        case 'D':
          flag=0;
          break;

        default:
          break
      }
    }
  if(flag){
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);
  delay(1000);
  }
}
```

The only issue with that is that while delaying between blinks its not testing for key presses, so to turn off the flag you'd have to hold 'D' for over two seconds, maybe even tap it. Its been a while since I used one of those keypads.